# Naming when splitting a data frame into new data frames

Tags: r

I'd like to create three new data frames based on the values of a variable (`df$pet`) so that I end up with dfdogCorrect, dfcatCorrect, and dfratCorrect.

The problem with my current code's that I can't get the naming of the new data frames to work. I'm using `unique(df$pet)`, and that takes the first unique element in pet and assigns it to the first new data frame, irrespective of the content of the new data frame.

Any help you be much appreciated.

starting point:

```
df <- data.frame(pet=c("dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","rat","rat","rat","rat"),relstatus=c(1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2),age=c(34,54,56,32,45,64,65,32,45), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

desired outcome:

```
dfdogCorrect <- data.frame(pet=c("dog","dog","dog"),relstatus=c(1,2,1),age=c(34,54,56), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dfcatCorrect <- data.frame(pet=c("cat","cat"),relstatus=c(2,2),age=c(32,45), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dfratCorrect <- data.frame(pet=c("rat","rat","rat","rat"),relstatus=c(2,2,1,2),age=c(64,65,32,45), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

current code:

```
s <- setNames(split(df, df$pet), paste0("df", unique(df$pet)))
list2env(s, globalenv())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the list names automatically by creating them in the `f` argument of `split()`.  I will not add the `list2env()` line because I think it's better to leave similar data in a list rather than scatter them into the global environment.

```
split(df, paste0("df", df$pet, "Correct"))
# $dfcatCorrect
#   pet relstatus age
# 4 cat         2  32
# 5 cat         2  45
# 
# $dfdogCorrect
#   pet relstatus age
# 1 dog         1  34
# 2 dog         2  54
# 3 dog         1  56
# 
# $dfratCorrect
#   pet relstatus age
# 6 rat         2  64
# 7 rat         2  65
# 8 rat         1  32
# 9 rat         2  45
```